# How to record microphone on macos with pyaudio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyaudio

I made a simple voice assistant in python with speech_recognition on Windows 10 and I wanted to copy the code for macOs too.

I downloaded PortAudio and PyAudio, the code runs fine but when i play the audio track I hear nothing :( (and the program not detect when I try to use the speech_recognition)
I guess it something with permissions and things like that... anyone have an idea?

( I also checked I use the right device index and I indeed use index 0 (The Mackbook built-in Microphone)

here is some code sample:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 1
fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
seconds = 3
filename = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

print('Recording')

stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                channels=channels,
                rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                input=True)

frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames

# Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)

# Stop and close the stream 
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
# Terminate the PortAudio interface
p.terminate()

print('Finished recording')

# Save the recorded data as a WAV file
wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(channels)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
wf.setframerate(fs)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Comment: This isn't a "pip" question. Its not really that where the problem is, its that you haven't done much research on how to change certain aspects of code when switching from Windows to a Linux based system.

Comment: @RedgarTech, no... I did it first on macOS like all the tutorials for macOS did, it didn't worked... then I switched to windows with the same code and it worked fine... I did a lot of research on this problem and everywhere the solution was the same (and it didn't worked for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer!!!

The code actually worked fine all this time, the problem was that I used `Visual Studio Code` that for some reason messed up with the microphone permissions 
Now I run the code through terminal with `python [filename].py` and its working great!